# To add zAxis dynamically, but doesn't work... Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i want do add **min** and **max** of zAxis with a function, but doesn't work, and i don't understand because it doesn't work :(

this is the function:

```
function assez(){
  var arr=[];    
  arr.push({
     min: -39,
     max: -35
    });    
  return arr;
 }
```

this zAxis:

```
  zAxis: assez(),
```

and this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/k0ahsch6/

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `xAxis` is `object`, not `array of objects`

```
function assez(){
    return {
        min: -39,
        max: -35
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is here **you actually need an Object not a array** because HighChart API says this:

```
Chart (Object options, Function callback)
```

After I change assez() to the following code, it works:

```
function assez(){
    var option=new Object();
    option.min = -39;
    option.max = -35;
    return option;
}
```